# Encoding XML in C#

Tags: c#, encoding

I have a xml file which has umlauts in it like so:

```
<NameGe>ËÇ</NameGe>
```

Is there a way to read this file and write it out like so:

```
<NameGe>&#214;&#231;</NameGe>
```

so basically it should write the numeric/encoded value of the umlaut.

Regards.

Comment: Why do you want to use entities rather than just letting the parser get on with it? (It makes no logical difference.) What character encoding are you using?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it by overriding `WriteString` of `XmlTextWriter`

```
MemoryStream m = new MemoryStream();
MyWriter xmlWriter = new MyWriter(m);

XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);
xDoc.Save(xmlWriter);
xmlWriter.Flush();

string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(m.ToArray());
```

-

```
public class MyWriter : XmlTextWriter
{
    public MyWriter(Stream s) : base(s,Encoding.UTF8)
    {
    }
    public override void WriteString(string text)
    {
        base.WriteRaw(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(text));
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent. Just one more thing how to change the header encoding of utf-16 to write utf-8?

Answer (score 3):

Use `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` and `HttpUtility.HtmlDecode`.

Comment: Tried that, it also applies to this '<' and '>'. Want something that would leave the tags as they are and just encode the values.

Comment: i'm not sure if this won't break the xml. why would you want that?

Comment: @cppanda - shouldn't break the xml; that is a standard xml representation of those characters, for writing to ASCII streams.