# Reading Xml files with umlaut chars

Tags: c#, xml, encoding

I have asked this question yesterday and got a reply.

[Writing encoded values for umlauts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11756403/encoding-xml-in-c-sharp)

In the code the parse method works if it's a string like so:

```
XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse("<description>Top Shelf-ÖÄÜookcase</description>");
```

To pass the input xml file as string, I have to read it first. The read method will fail if there are umlauts in the input xml.
How do I get past that?

Tried both Load and Parse methods of XDocument.

Load:
Invalid character in the given encoding. Line 3, position 35.
Parse:
Data at the root level is invalid. Line 1, position 1.

Here is a sample xml after using CDATA:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<kal>
 <description><![CDATA[Top Shelf-ÖÄÜookcase]]> </description> 
</kal>
```

Answer (score 4):

Change encoding to "iso-8859-1"

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried wrapping the description data with a [CDATA](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect)?

```
<description><![CDATA[Top Shelf-ÖÄÜookcase]]> </description>
```

Special characters don't particularly parse well in XML unless you wrap them with CDATA.

Comment: Creating the incoming xml is not in my hand. But I have already told that to the other party responsible for creating this incoming xml.

Comment: Even CDATA both the Load and Parse methods dont work!!! I have added a sample xml, if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

As [Besi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1032927/besi) stated, you have to use the correct encoding of the xml-file in order to achieve correct handling of the umlauts.

Even so you said that the creation of the incoming xml-file is not in your hand, you can still affect the encoding to use for parsing the xml by using a dedicated `StreamReader`:

```
//  create your XDocument
XDocument Doc;

//  setup a StreamReader for your file, specifying the encoding you need
using (StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(@"C:\your-file.xml", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1")))
{
    //  PARSE the STRING that is RETURNED from the StreamReader.ReadToEnd()-method
    Doc = XDocument.Parse(Reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```